# How to understand and read Jenkins plugin syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not a programer, but I'm working towards DevOps. At times I find the Jenkins syntax and Documentation is poor and hard to understand. For example when we want to write a Pipeline as a code, the plugin Syntax doesn't make any sense. The documentation is confusing atleast to me. Is it a method or a property/parameter or a List or an object and how do use those methods etc in a Jenkins pipeline Code? Can somone take an example plugin and explain/interpret the relavent syntax documentation that was on their website and an exmaple Jenkins pipeline code using that please? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Read this [page](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/getting-started-with-shared-libraries-in-jenkins) from Cloudbees. It also has a video if you scroll all the way down.

Comment: Have you the [book](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), referenced the [pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) or tied to make use of the [snippet generator](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator). Also, be sure to understand whether you are looking at scripted (flexible) vs declarative (simple).

Comment: Thank you . plugin syntax is the problem. Ex, take NexusArtifactUploader plugin doc. First of all, 'nexusArtifactUploader' is it ia method like nexusArtifactUploader() or a block like nexusArtifactUploader{}, how do I know? Then Underneath that I see 'nexusVersion', 'protocol', 'nexusUrl' etc, Are they parameters? How do you use them syntactically? So will it be nexustsArtifactUploader(nexusVersion:'1.0.0',protocol:'https') etc or nexusArtifact{nexusVersion:'1.0.0',protocol:'https'} or nexusArtifact[nexusVersion:'1.0.0',protocol:'https']? This is where the difficulty is for Any plugin.